# Template String Substitution that supports spaces in object keys

Tags: javascript

How to do template strings substitution for templates that can have spaces in them?
I have looked at handlebars' but I want to use something small on the client side.

Example Input String:

```
We are from {{Business Name}}. This month we sold {{Sales Quantity Pounds}} of {{Sales Item}} for a total profit of {{Sales Total Quarter 4}}.
```

Example Data:

```
{
    "Business Name": "Acme International",
    "Sales Quantity Pounds": "198",
    "Sales Item": "567",
    "Sales Total Quarter 4": "$ 74370"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.replace()` method with a regular expression to select all occurrences of `{{<text>}}` in your string, while also grouping `<text>`, allowing you to use the replacement function to return the value stored at the key `<text>`.

See example below:

```js
const str = "We are from {{Business Name}}. This month we sold {{Sales Quantity Pounds}} of {{Sales Item}} for a total profit of {{Sales Total Quarter 4}}.";

const obj = {
    "Business Name": "Acme International",
    "Sales Quantity Pounds": "198",
    "Sales Item": "567",
    "Sales Total Quarter 4": "$ 74370"
};


const res = str.replace(/\{\{([^\}\}]+)\}\}/g, (_, g) => obj[g]);
console.log(res);
```

Regex explanation:

- `\{\{`: Match two open curly brackets
- `([^\}\}]+)`: Continue to match any characters that are not two closed curly brackets, and group them using a capture group `()`, which you can refer to in your replacement function (as `g`).
- `\}\}`: Match two closing curly brackets.
- `/g`: Global flag to match all occurrences of this pattern across the string.

---

Another option is to use a node module such as [string-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-template). This does require that your string uses single curly brackets to denote the keys within your object as well as it requiring your object keys to be one word:

```
const format = require("string-template");
const str = "We are from {BusinessName}. This month we sold {SalesQuantityPounds} of {SalesItem} for a total profit of {SalesTotalQuarter4}.";
const res = format(str, {
  "BusinessName": "Acme International",
  "SalesQuantityPounds": "198",
  "SalesItem": "567",
  "SalesTotalQuarter4": "$ 74370"
});
```